# Why do IUnknown* pointers retrieved through different interfaces of the same COM object have the same value?

Tags: c++, windows, inheritance, com, multiple-inheritance

I have the following hierarchy of COM interfaces and a class implementing them:

```
interface IX : public IUnknown{};
interface IY : public IUnknown{};
class CA: public IX, public IY{};
```

Here `class CA` effectively inherits from `IUnknown` twice.

We know there are two vtable pointers in `class CA` - one is pointed to `IX` and another is pointed to `IY`. So `IUnknown` stored in the `IX` subobject is different from `IUnknown` stored in the `IY` subobject.

Yet when we call `IX::QueryInterface()` or `IY::QueryInterface()` on the same object and query `IUnknown` we get identical `IUnknown*` pointers.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Thank you for edit my questions, JaredPar.    My English is poor. thank you every much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's so called ["object identity" requirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that states that whenever you request `IUnknown` from two objects you get distinct pointers if those are distinct objects and equal pointers if that's the same object.

Every `QueryInterface()` implementation must fulfill this requirement. This is usually done by [choosing which one `IUnknown` to return and sticking to it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1742329):

```
HRESULT CA::QueryInterface( REFIID iid, void** ppv )
{
    if( iid == __uuidof( IUnknown ) ) {
        // Explicitly cast to one of base class subobjects.
        // Doesn't matter which one is chosen - it just has to be
        // the same base class subobject each time IUnknown is requested.
       IUnknown* selected = static_cast<IX*>( this );
       *ppv = selected;
       AddRef();
       return S_OK;
    } else {
       continue for other interfaces
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, But I want to know how do QueryInterface implement returning the same IUnknow pointer while there have more than one IUnknow interface.

Comment: @kenny: Easy, they just cast to one of them each time - see the linked to question.