# How to test for equality of audio sessions

Tags: c++, winapi, com, core-audio, wasapi

I am trying to use the Windows Audio Session API to locate the default audio session within the enumeration of current audio sessions.  Currently I have a reference to the [`IAudioSessionControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368246%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the default session of the audio render endpoint in the [`eConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370842%28VS.85%29.aspx) role as well as an [`IAudioSessionEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368281%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object that enumerates the audio sessions of this default endpoint, but I need to be able to compare the `IAudioSessionControl` object that I have for equality with the `IAudioSessionControl` objects returned by [`IAudioSessionEnumerator::GetSession`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368286%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

I was hoping that I could test for equality by comparing the `IAudioSessionControl` pointers for equality. This works when I obtain the `IAudioSessionControl` for the default session multiple times using [`IAudioClient::GetService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370873%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately, this pointer returned by `IAudioClient::GetService` does not appear in the enumeration of audio sessions by the `IAudioSessionEnumerator`. Also, obtaining the default audio session multiple times via the [`IAudioSessionManager::GetAudioSessionControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370963%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) route does not yield identical `IAudioSessionControl` pointers even when using the same audio session GUID (`GUID_NULL`) and `CrossProcessSession` value.

How do I test for equality of audio sessions given two `IAudioSessionControl` pointers? Is it possible to obtain the audio session GUID and process identifier of a given `IAudioSessionControl` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [IAudioSessionControl2::GetSessionIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368252%28VS.85%29.aspx) API, that's what the audio subsystem uses to persist session volumes.  If you want to distinguish sessions at runtime (two instances of the same app running at the same time), check the [GetSessionInstanceIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368255%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing COM can help you with here is [object identity requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753000/57428).

You query `IUnknown*` from both objects and compare them. If `IUnknown*` of those objects is the same it's the same object, otherwise those are distinct objects.

Of course the implementation could violate the object identity requirement or those distinct objects might somehow map onto the same internal object. COM can't help you here - you have to find information specific to that component implementation.